# .htaccess redirect to index.php - 404 error not working

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I'm trying to setup .htaccess for my website. I want to redirect user to index.php if is entered wrong url address. But when I enter wrong url It does not redirect me to index.php but it shows me an error(Not Found 404 error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument).

My .htaccess file

```
Options -Indexes
DirectoryIndex index.php

<IFModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /rop/
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-\/&_]+)/?$ index.php?etc=$1 [L]
</IfModule>

<Files config.php>
deny from all
</Files>

ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
ErrorDocument 403 /rop/pages/error/403.html
```

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1):

Do you use localhost? This is work for me.

```
ErrorDocument 404 http://localhost/[your folder name]/index.php
```

Answer (score 0):

It is due to your rewrite rule and `ErrorDocument` directives that are stepping over each other.

Your rewrite rule is this:

```
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-\/&_]+)/?$ index.php?etc=$1 [L]
```

Which essentially means:

**If request is not for a file/directory (not found) then forward to `index.php?etc=<uri>`.**

Now you also have `ErrorDocument` directive like this:

```
 ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
```

**If something is not found then forward to `/index.php`.**

PS: Your regex is also incorrect in rewrite rule.

Comment: Thank you ... but can you help me to fix it ?

Comment: I need to know your requirements first. Why are you rewriting to `/index.php?etc=` and using `ErrorDocument` at the same time? Provide some details.

Comment: I want to create pretty seo url's .. such as "domain.com/user/profile" .. then I parse URL segments (PHP). When user enters wrong url "domain.com/user/profile/asdad!)_asda/" then I want to redirect him to index.php .. For other errors I would use error Documents (403.html, 500.html and so on..).